# Getting values with preg_match_all

Tags: php

How can I get each value returned by PHP `preg_match_all` using for each loop, because I want to insert each value in database.
Thanks

Comment: The manual has an example: See example #2 [here](http://php.net/preg_match_all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/pattern/', $haystack, $matches);
foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
    echo $match;
}
```

The third parameter is the variable where the matches will be stored.
You can use `print_r($matches)` to see the structure of the array and design your code accordingly